# How can I trigger a Leaflet map to reload everything including the overlay layers?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm having an issue right now with my map where I need to export it as an image with the overlay layers. I found a solution to do so using html2canvas, however there is a bug with it where if you pan the map at all, when taking the screenshot the layers will not display properly in the screenshot from html2canvas like so...

[image]

Yet if I just change the center of my map with  map.setView() it works fine. So my thought is, if I could just trigger the map to reload completely (including the layers) it would maybe overlay correctly. **How can I trigger a Leaflet map to reload everything including the overlay layers?**

I've looked through the documentation but haven't as of this second found a clear solution.

Comment: I'm gonna guess that you don't want to reload everything, but want to do a `map.invalidateSize()` instead. Check the docs. And check the sheer number of questions here on SO which are solved by the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the view to some random place in the ocean and then changing it back worked.

```
function redraw() {
    var lat_tmp = map.getCenter().lat;
    var lng_tmp = map.getCenter().lng;
    map.setView([-66.22149259832975, -1.142578125]);
    console.log("Reloading...");
    setTimeout(function () {
        waitForTilesToLoad()
    }, 50000);
    map.setView([lat_tmp, lng_tmp]);
    console.log("Done");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem today. It also happened with an export by dom-to-image-more/lealfet-easy-print plugin.

Try to disable zoomSnap or try to deactivate the fractional zoom functionality.